# WordPress Update to 5.6.1 - still keeps Version 5.5.3

Tags: wordpress

I have to update WordPress to version 5.6.1. There is no error bat it keeps on version 5.5.3 with hint there is an update to version 5.6.1.

I see the progress info

- its downloading 5.6.1.
- unpacked successfully
- installed successfully
  But it opens 5.5.3 info

Comment: How do you know it keeps the  ```5.5.3``` version then?

Comment: I see the welcome with version 5.5.3 and still hint for update to 5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it works. I installed jQuery Migrate. After new login, there was a message for  updateing database. Now its on 5.6.1